# Question about connected, closed subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, connectedness

I have to prove that for a connected, closed subgroup $G$ of $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$, then $\exp(L) = G$ where $L = \{X \in M_n(\mathbb{C}) \mid \forall t \in \mathbb{R}, \exp(t X)\in G\}$.

I can prove that $\exp(L)$ is an open set (by proving that $\exp$ is a $C^1$-diffeomorphism around $0$, and then by translating).

But, I wasn't able to prove that $\exp(L)$ is closed (I tried to express $G-\exp(L)$ as a union of open set).

Edit :
The previous result is false as stated in the commentary.

I haven't understood the question of my book . I have to prove that G is the subgroup generated by the elements of $\exp(L) $.

Comment: *Hint*: Prove that $L$ is closed under the Lie bracket.

Comment: You cannot prove it, because it is false in general. For instance it is false for $Sl(2,R)$ wich is a closed connected subgroup of $GL(2,C)$. Se exercise page 75 in Dragomir Z. Djokovic et Karl H. Hofmann, « The surjectivity question for the exponential function of real Lie groups: A status report », Journal of Lie Theory, vol. 7,‎ 1997, p. 171-199  https://books.google.fr/books?id=didACQAAQBAJ&pg=PA75&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: Thank you for the answer and for the reference. I edited the post.

Comment: Assume $g\in G$, since $G$ Is connected, there exist a path $\gamma$ from $e$, the unit, to $g$. As in your post, $exp(L)$ is open. So $\{g\exp(L)\}_{g\in \gamma}$ is a open cover of $\gamma[0,1]$. Is this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $g\in G$, since $G$ is connected, there exist a path $\gamma$ from $e$, the unit, to $g$. As in your post, $exp(L)$ is open. So ${g\exp(L)}_{g\in \gamma}$ is a open cover of $\gamma[0,1]$. The compactness shows there is a finite subcover. Suppose $h_1\in exp(L)\cap g_{1}exp(L)$, then $h_1=exp(L_1)=g_1 exp(L_2)$, this implies $g_1=exp(L_1)exp(-L_2)$. Deduce like this that $g$ can be represented by finite product of $exp(L_i)$.

In fact, this holds for arbitrary Banach algebra, you can see Rudin’s Functional Analysis,theorem 10.34 for more details.
As Thomas said in comments. $exp(L)=G$ is false in general, but if $G$ is Abel, $exp(L)=G$ is true.

Comment: This is fine. But I am not sure about the fact that G connected implies G is a path-connected space.

Comment: @jvc This is true, because $G$ is Lie group, it is local path connected. There is a theorem in general topology states that connected plus local path connected implies path connected.